# Optimizing string replacement query, large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

Apply statement super slow

```
 df['col'] = df['col'].apply(
                            lambda x: "Large" if len(str(x))>32000 else x)
```

Cant use np where

```
df['col'] = np.where(len(str(df['col']))>32000, ['Large'], df['col'])
```

Comment: Are these not strings to begin with? The `str(x)` seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.str` accessor:

```
df.x.str
Out[3]: <pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods at 0x1e4be07a2b0>
```

to do vectorized string operations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": ["hello", "x"*32001]
})


df['col'] = np.where(df.x.str.len()>32000, ['Large'], df.x)
```

Result:

```
                                                   x    col
0                                              hello  hello
1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...  Large
```